# how to parse the json array elements using for loop to get the values one by one

Tags: php, json, parsing

i have a json array wherer i would like to pasre the json till the last element by using for loop for that i would like to get the number of array elements in the json array ,i have more than 3 objects in anarray ,so i am confused how to parse the json till the last element,
i can say you the idea

```
Count($json);
 echo count;
  for(i=0;i<l=count($json);i++)
 {
 then print the value of each key
 }
```

i am stuck ,because there is no fixed lenght for the json i am getting as it is a server response it may return one object one may be twice or thrice or many ,so i thought it would be better to do with for loop ,as a json contain more than one json with 3 keys ,such as country can have more than one state,and one state can have more than one district ,plaese help me,i am stuck with question for last 2 days
thank you

Comment: You can make a PHP function with the json array in param, and recall the function if current value `is_array`, print else!

Answer (score 1):

An idea :

```
function printJson($json) {
       foreach($json as $index=>$value) {
           if(is_array($value)) {
               printJson($value);
           } else {
               echo 'Value :'.$value.'<br />';
           }
       }

}
$stringJson = "{'location':[{...}]}"; //for example
printJson(json_decode($stringJson));
```

Comment: my json is [{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"},{"location":[{"building":["test_loc1_building1","test_loc1_building2"],"name":"test location1"},{"building":["test_loc2_building2"],"name":"test location2"}],"name":"test Organization"}]

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively decode the json tring using `json_decode()` which will give u a php variable which u can then easily iterate over using php.

eg.

```
$string = '{"image":"fox.png","puzzlepieces":{"f":{"puzzlepiece":"one","position":"top:121px;left:389px;"},"x":{"puzzlepiece":"three","position":"top:164px;left:455px;"},"o":{"puzzlepiece":"two","position":"top:52px;left:435px;"}}}';

var_dump(json_decode($string));
```

will output as

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'image' => string 'fox.png' (length=7)
  public 'puzzlepieces' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'f' => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'puzzlepiece' => string 'one' (length=3)
          public 'position' => string 'top:121px;left:389px;' (length=21)
      public 'x' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'puzzlepiece' => string 'three' (length=5)
          public 'position' => string 'top:164px;left:455px;' (length=21)
      public 'o' => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'puzzlepiece' => string 'two' (length=3)
          public 'position' => string 'top:52px;left:435px;' (length=20)
```

My xdebug extension is on in WAMP so your var_dump might be a little differently formatted but overall you'd get a php variable from the array which u can iterate using `foreach` or other loops.

Read more on json_decode [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)